# How to deploy a React App with basepath + nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx

everyone !

I'm trying deploy a react app to production.

My case.

In production, my application will have a dynamic basepath and i change it in build.

Example:

- example.com/basepath
- example.com/basepath2

my package.json

```json
...
"scripts": {
 "build:basepath": "PUBLIC_URL=basepath react-app-rewired build",
 "build:basepath2": "PUBLIC_URL=basepath2 react-app-rewired build",
}
```

In my routes is setted basename with dynamic basepath

my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    error_page 400 404 405 =200 @40*_json;

    location @40*_json {
      default_type application/json;
      return 200 '{"code":"1", "message": "Not Found"}';
    }

    location ~ /basepath{
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     try_files $uri /basepath/index.html;
    }

}
```

I can access app by example.com/basepath. Its work

If i access example.com/basepath/ receive a blank page

accessing example.com/basepath, the chunks are downloaded in example.com/basepath/statics/chank....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNcIK.jpg

accessing example.com/basepath/ the chunks url is wrong example.com**/basepath/basepath/**statics/chank....

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ksv5.png

When routes are changed by app links, its all ok

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fj0h.jpg

I don't know if error is in nginx or in react router

Some idea ?

sorry for my english, and this is my first topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter?

Comment: this is a validated answer, so it probably correct in this case, but it would help future user if you explain a bit more why this change solve the issue :)